# How to format date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery/JavaScript to convert a date. I have turned the string into a object, but I just don't know how to get the results that I am looking for.

```
var dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
var dateFormatted = ???
```

How can I format a date such as 10/12/2014 into this `Sun Oct 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)` in jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: ahh... the ageless awful question... even here on SO, there must be dozens of attempts at this. Best bet, use a library, or use code from a library

Comment: Agreed that a library is your best bet. I don't like suggesting libraries though, but moment.js is too good for dates: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: great, thanks for your help and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Moment.js is great, but don't you think it's a bit overkill for this?

Comment: @Mercury Explain "overkill". Because it's a huge library (10kb, smaller gzipped) that will slow down the page? Because it provides excellent date parsing/formatting? Because it's easy to learn and use? Because it can improve the rest of a website if learned and applied properly?

Comment: No, I think moment is great-- especially if you're using it for multiple purposes.  If you only need it to reformat a date in one piece of the code, though, it's probably more beneficial to take the functionality you need from it and just use that rather than loading the whole library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use moment.js and want your desired format which I know is the HttpDate format the correct syntax is

```
var nowInHttpDate = moment().format("ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ");
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easiest to use a library that is already written to modify dates. I would suggest moment.js, which can be found at momentjs.com. Then you can just write something like:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // July 9th 2014, 2:32:08 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using new Date() and passing in your string.  The Date constructor has quite a bit of magic in regards to the formats it can take as an input.  This should work:

```
dateStr = '10/12/2014';
date = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(date);        // logs Sun Oct 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Mine outputs `Sun Oct 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`. The "magic" in the date constructor is inconsistent and has poor parsing ability, as well as locality

Comment: The only inconsistency there is the locality.  Depending on the purpose of your application, you might want that to change to better suit the user.  Again, it's all dependent on context.